# best / quick way to remove character from string at a given index (swift 4)

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to remove the third character from a string. however, there does not seem to be a clean way to do this. I couldn't find an extension that does this and using a library is a bit overkill

I probably could take the first start range up to this character, then the last range and concatenating these together feels quite wrong and there must be a better way IMO

Any help is appreciated!, Thanks!

Comment: Did not see that post however it does not contain working code for swift 4 so still no answer to my question

Comment: It has a Swift 4 answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that the below way:

```
var str = "I am Bla Bla"
if str.count > 2 {
    str.remove(at: String.Index(encodedOffset: 2))
    print(str)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! This seems to be working for swift 4